# Why gcc4 warn and how to avoid it

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning, gcc4

I have a function declared as:

```
void    event_add_card (EventAddr addr, EventType type, unsigned char card);
```

and union

```
typedef union EventData
{
    float           money;      /**< money info */
    unsigned char   card;       /**< new card */
}
EventData;
```

When i compile following code:

```
EventData data = {};

event_add_card (0,0, data.card);
```

with enabled warning `-Wconversion` I receive following warning:

```
player-stud.c|71| warning: passing argument 3 of 'event_add_card' with different width due to prototype
```

Why gcc4 unsuccessful and how to fix It???

Comment: Bcause of the union. Are you sure you are not intedning to define it as a struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In versions of gcc prior to 4.3, `-Wconversion` produces a warning when the behaviour may be different depending on whether or not a prototype is in scope.  In the example you give, argument 3 (`data.card`) is of `unsigned char`; if the prototype for `event_add_card()` is in scope, it will be passed as an `unsigned char`, but if the prototype is not in scope it will be passed as an `int` due to C's integer promotion rules - hence the warning.

This isn't very useful, except during the process of converting old K&R-style code to use prototypes.  As such, if you're using an older version of gcc, it's not a generally useful option to enable.

From gcc 4.3 onwards, the behaviour has changed: it now warns about any implicit conversion which might change a value (say, between signed and unsigned integers, or integers and floats).  This is considerably more useful.  (The previous functionality hasn't gone, though: it's still available, but renamed as `-Wtraditional-conversion`.)

(More details at http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion .)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using -Wconversion

There is nothing wrong with your code, and nothing you can do to make -Wconversion not produce that warning.

Example:

```
void someFunction(unsigned char foo);
...
unsigned char bar = 'f';
someFunction(bar);
```

This will produce the same error if you compile and use -Wconversion

-Wconversion is meant to identify issues when converting between K&R and ISO C, which you aren't doing.